# Angular ui-router specific treatment for unknown state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on multiple angular apps that I have to nest (like a web portal). My main app got a router where I define some states.

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
        url: "/state1",
        views: {

            "area": { templateUrl: "area1.html"}
        }
    });
```

And my other apps work like this too. I'd like to make a specific script that would be called if the state called in the main app is unknown by the main router, so I could to get the url and views in another router.

For example, if the main app call the state `state2` that is unknown by my first router, it will look for it in a second router which define it.

I looked for a solution using the `resolve` option of `ui-router` but I'm not sure it could work this way.

Feel free to ask for more details. I did my best to make it short and understandable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Documentation on [Otherwise()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes)

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // if the path doesn't match any of the urls you configured
    // otherwise will take care of routing the user to the specified url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');

    // Example of using function rule as param
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
        ... some advanced code...
    });
})
```

Comment: I thought about it just after creating the question ! So, as I can use some advanced code in the `otherwise`, it should work with my specific needs. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you as your need:

```
var myApp =   angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');
$urlRouterProvider.when("", "/state1");
$stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: '/state1',
            templateUrl: 'state1.php'
            }
        })
        .state("state2", {
            url: "/state2",
            templateUrl: 'state2.php'
         });
});
```

Comment: In your case, both states are in the same router. I don't think it matches with my question :/

Comment: No, you get wrong to understand my answer. You said about $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');
$urlRouterProvider.when("", "/state1");
So I have answered for this. not for "$stateProvider...". 
You can write your default url in 'Otherwise', if url is not accessible.

Comment: I just add whole code for better understanding. Otherwise mine is perfect solution.